# Can't instantiate Coordinate Resource System java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.geotools.factory.Hints

Tags: android, gradle, geotools, android-multidex

I am trying to use the Geotools Java library in a project of mine an I built it using Gradle and version 14.3:

```
compile 'org.geotools:gt-shapefile:14.3'
compile 'org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:14.3'
```

Basically, any time I try to instantiate a CoordinateResourceSystem, such as:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs;
try {
     crs = CRS.decode("epsg:4326"); //also tried DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84_3D
} catch (FactoryException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get this error at runtime:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.geotools.factory.Hints
at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.<clinit>(CRS.java:181)
```

All of the advice I've received until now has had to do with enabling Multidex and I have tried every single one of the combinations of gradle prescribed, but to no avail. Also tried cleaning and building dozens of times. No matter what I do I receive this pesky error at runtime. Any thoughts as to why this could be? I can see the class in the jar.

I have noticed that this dependency imports several jars, all with similar package names. Could these package names be causing some confusion?

Really at a loss here and I can't continue with my project until I've figured out how to implement this code properly.

*EDIT*

Here's my logcat. Showing that there seems to be some kind of issue with how ART deals with some of the geotools classes, including the culrpit Hints class.

```
04-20 22:41:55.308 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingFactory>
04-20 22:41:55.311 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints>
04-20 22:41:55.311 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints$Key>
04-20 22:41:55.319 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints>
04-20 22:41:55.324 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory>
04-20 22:41:55.324 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.referencing.DefaultAuthorityFactory>
04-20 22:41:55.325 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints>
04-20 22:41:55.326 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints$Key>
04-20 22:41:55.326 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints$Key>
04-20 22:41:55.329 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints>
04-20 22:41:55.329 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.referencing.factory.AbstractAuthorityFactory>
04-20 22:41:55.330 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.referencing.factory.AbstractAuthorityFactory>
04-20 22:41:55.330 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints>
04-20 22:41:55.339 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.geometry.DirectPosition2D>
04-20 22:41:55.341 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints>
04-20 22:41:55.342 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints$Key>
04-20 22:41:55.355 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.357 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.358 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.359 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.360 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.361 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.362 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.363 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.363 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.364 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.365 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.366 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.367 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.368 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.371 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.372 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.374 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.375 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.376 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.376 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.377 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.378 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.378 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.379 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.379 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.383 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.384 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.384 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.389 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderableOp>
04-20 22:41:55.402 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.406 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderedOp>
04-20 22:41:55.406 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.PlanarImage>
04-20 22:41:55.408 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderableOp>
04-20 22:41:55.409 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderableOp>
04-20 22:41:55.410 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.RenderableOp>
04-20 22:41:55.414 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<javax.media.jai.JAI$RenderingKey>
04-20 22:41:55.414 5089-5089/com.myproject I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.geotools.factory.Hints>
04-20 22:41:55.414 5089-5089/com.myproject D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-20 22:41:55.415 5089-5089/com.myproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                               Process: com.myproject, PID: 5089
                                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.geotools.factory.Hints
                                                                                                   at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.<clinit>(CRS.java:181)
                                                                                                   at com.myproject.MotionTrackingActivity.onCreate(MotionTrackingActivity.java:122)
                                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2160)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2246)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:136)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5030)
                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
```

Answer (score 2):

The "usual way" to break GeoTools referencing is to not include an EPSG factory or the include more than one. From your question I can't tell which is your problem. As described in the [FAQ](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/faq.html) you need one of the `epsg` jars, usually `gt-epsg-hsql`.

Your question is tagged Android and there are [some known issues](https://github.com/jodygarnett/geotools-andriod) with the SPI based factory finder system that GeoTools uses but I don't think that should be this issue.

Comment: included the gt-epsg-hsql dependency. still getting that same error :( any other ideas what might be causing this? might just try another library, so would also be open to suggestions for libraries that for sure work with android. thanks for the answer...

Comment: Ian, did you ever get a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I don't know anything about gradle so I'm stuck

Comment: Still a problem in 2020. Encountering it.  @ethan did you got a solution for this?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54423871/nosuchauthoritycodeexcpetion-in-geotools-program-gradle-build-converting-betwe for a working gradle example